# Can not use dump in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, dump

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. 
Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

I want to use dump to make a backup.

But when I use pip install dump and run：

```
root@zwk-virtual-machine:/sbin# dump -0f /mnt/lvm/rootfs-20160824.bak / 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/dump", line 7, in <module> from dump import console
ImportError: cannot import name console
```

When I uninstall dump and try to apt-get install dump, then:

```
root@zwk-virtual-machine:/sbin# dump -0f /mnt/lvm/rootfs-20160824.bak / 
bash: /usr/local/bin/dump: No such file or directory
```

the file dump.py after pip install like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from dump import console

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(console())
```

Could somebody give me some advice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your file is called dump.py which hides the dump library you have installed. Call your file something else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I rename dump.py to dum.py and then use `alias dump='dum'`.  But when I run `from dump import console` in python interactive mod. It still tell me `ImportError: cannot import name console`.  But there exist def `console` in `__main__.py` at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dump`. Do you know why it happens? Thanks.